# Automatic release of objects when using Castle Windsor

Tags: dependency-injection, castle-windsor

I'm starting a new project and I'm looking into using a dependency container (Castle Windsor) to help when it comes to unit testing. One of the things that is a little frustrating is that after I've finished using an object I have to tell the container to "release" the object.

I understand the reasoning behind doing this, but it's still cumbersome to have to remember to do this. So, my question is, is there a way I can make the "releasing" of an object automatic so I don't have to remember to release it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should apply the [Register Resolve Release](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/09/29/TheRegisterResolveReleasePattern.aspx) pattern in the application's **Composition Root**.

You should **release what you create**, but since you should only have a **single line of code that resolves objects**, you'll also only need a **single line of code that releases those objects**.

In other words, you don't have to remember anything because once you have that little piece of infrastructure in place, you should never have to think about it again.

Comment: I have just been looking at Ninject and I like the approach it takes to the automatic relasing of objects whereby you create a "Activation Context", retrieve objects using the context and dispose of the context at the end to release the objects. What are your thoughts on this approach?

Comment: Autofac does the same thing, and I'm not particularly fond of this approach, which makes things extra difficult when the release point is different from the resolve point. This happens often, e.g. in ASP.NET MVC's IControllerFactory or WCF's IInstanceProvider. The only way to make instance scopes work across method boundaries is to create an association of the resolved object and its scope - and you'll need to make sure it's thread-safe. A Release method (like Windsor's) does this automatically for you.

Comment: @MotoSV @Mark Seemann: Recent work on Ninject is unifying the (currently internal [to Ninject.Web] OnePerRequestModule) and its approach of allowing one to call a Release method as Mark is referring to